# How to reharmonize a sample already with heavy harmony?

Tags: harmony, production

If one is to reharmonize a sample, let's say, a full song with its own chords that can be clearly heard, how can one make sure the new chords do not clash with the existing ones? I want reharmonization strategies, not audio editing ones, for example, use plugins to lower the volume of the old chords.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want the new chords to clash with the old chords, as long as they're not playing at the same time? Heck, I reharmonized a passage last month with C in the bass instead of C#, and a piece I transcribed earlier this year reharmonized the same melody 3 times with (all bassline notes) G (whole note) -> Db (whole note), D (whole note) -> G (whole note), and A -> Ab -> G -> Gb -> Db (even nastier, starting melody notes against the last bassline were Ab -> G -> F -> C -> Bb).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Using an unedited sample means that the OP is using a piece of an existing recording without trying to remove the old chords. So the old and new harmonies will be playing at the same time.

Comment: @ojs - Are we sure the question asker is using unedited samples only? The impression I get is that the question asker will be editing their sample but does not want answers about audio editing such as "duck out the old chords" - they want answers that help them determine which new chords to use so, when they remove the old chords, they already know which new chords they will put in.

Comment: @Dekkadeci it's not explicitly mentioned, but I think there's not much point to asking the question and mentioning the existing chords if they are going to edit them away in any case.

Comment: @ojs - I thought the question asker mentioned that they want to "make sure the new chords do not clash with the existing ones" only for some aesthetic or conceptual reason. Honestly, I'd think pretty much *any* reharmonization will clash with the old chords somewhere.

Comment: @Dekkadeci yes they mentioned that. I'm not sure why they would mention existing chords if they were planning to edit them out. There is an answer that explains some ways it could be accomplished.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, you're going to get a composite of the original harmony and whatever harmony you add.   And if the original is fully voiced with bass line, chords and melody your options are going to be limited!  Particularly if you want the result to make sense in harmony terms, not just be an 'effect' of clashing harmonies played together.

If there isn't  a low bass line, you could write a new one.   C major with C in the bass is one thing, with A in the bass it's another (Am7).   In the internal harmony you could add notes - 6ths and 9ths often do no harm.   Or you could add upper structure - a D triad over C7 adds up to C13♯11.

But I'm not sure you've fully thought this concept through.